# Add Some Text message on top of standard detail page using JavaScript No VF Page

Tags: detail-page

Can we add some sample text message on standard detail page as shown in the below screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Probably not, but you can show the message differently based on your use-case?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately thats not possible using pure JavaScript Solution.

You have two options here:

- Use the Visualforce page option.
- Create custom detail page using apex:detail tag and then add your custom message as well.